# What are candies used for?

Tags: dont-touch-the-spikes

In **Don't touch the spikes**, there are little orange candies to be collected. Is there any use for them, rather than just have them appear in the menu screen (The amount you've collected)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are used to buy the birds. Just click the bird icon on the menu screen to see what I am talking about:

[image]

(Sorry about the clash of clans notification)

Comment: Epic invasion, though